# What does "(Install)" mean in a package?

Tags: chocolatey

example: https://chocolatey.org/packages?q=notepad%2B%2B

Does Chocolatey run the native program installer? If I prefer simplicity, should I avoid packages with `(Install)` in their name?

Comment: If used properly, it's likely a package that works with a native installer like MSI, InnoSetup, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excerpt from Chocolatey.org:

> This package is likely a meta/virtual (*) or an installer (*.install) or portable (*.portable) application package.
>
> [...]
>
> - Install (*.install/*.app (deprecated naming convention)) - uses native installers, usually requires administrative access to install.

Whether you should avoid them or not is a question of opinion. You should form your own opinions.